# How to pass parameters in hive query when executing using impyla?

Tags: python, hive, parameter-passing, hiveql, impyla

I referred to [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python/50497904#50497904)

but couldn't get an answer.

I am trying what you suggested, but I get this error - :(

```
tbl_nm = 'EMPLOYEE_TABLE'

con.execute('select max(emp_id) from schema.?', tbl_nm)
```

Getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 302,

in execute configuration=configuration) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 343,

in execute_async self._execute_async(op) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 362,

in _execute_async operation_fn() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 334,

in op parameters) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/interface.py", line 267,

in _bind_parameters

raise ProgrammingError("Query parameters argument should be a "
impala.error.ProgrammingError: Query parameters argument should be a list, tuple, or dict object

>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing raw hive query directly to execute method, it is recommended that you store your query as a string into a variable and pass it to execute method.

In your case:

```
tbl_nm = 'EMPLOYEE_TABLE'
query = "select max(emp_id) from schema.{}".format(tbl_nm)
con.execute(query)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you - after posting this question I figured out the answer. How can I execute a hiveql script in python. example - I have a .hql script load_emp_table.hql which contains a series of queries:

Comment: Thank you - after posting this question I figured out the answer. How can I execute a hiveql script in python. example - I have a .hql script load_emp_table.hql which contains a series of queries:

Before the query can to be executed, all the parameters needs to be resolved.
tbl_nm1 = emp_stg_tbl
tbl_nm = emp_tbl
schema_name = emp_schema


load_emp_table.hql

use ${schema_name};

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ${schema_name}.${tbl_nm1}
select * from 
     ${schema_name}.${tbl_nm}

Comment: You can parse the HQL file and using regex, replace the ${schema_name} and ${tbl_nm1} with the variables(which 
inturn store the actual schema_name and tbl_nm) and then pass that string to execute method.

These variables can be passed to python as arguments and you may replace the "$" strings in the HQL file.
If the schema_name and tbl_nm come dynamically, find a way to store them into local variables 
in the python program and use them.

Comment: Thank you - i did exactly the same thing. It is working. I used replace to replace ${tbl_nm} with actual table name and re frame the query